# Coolest looking terminal IRC client

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, irc

I am looking for a IRC client for the terminal that has colors, user list and just generally looks awesome ;)
Any recommendations? There are loads of IRC clients in the repositories and I don't want to download them all to find the best one.

Comment: this question is way too subjective.
as txwikinger said: a community wiki with a list of IRC clients (screenshots, features, pros/cons) would make more sense

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/8015/what-irc-clients-are-available/349822#349822

Comment: Right, but what if you run it inside screen? I haven't been able to make irssi to have a nicklist. Also, what about multi-tab?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

IRSSI - The client of the future http://www.irssi.org/

```
sudo apt-get install irssi
```

Say no more

[image]

Comment: I use irssi myself and I definitely agree abut it being a great IRC client. Yet, I wonder what makes it the "coolest looking" one?

Comment: It has a variety of [http://www.irssi.org/themes themes] to be used with. But the greatest strength is the amount of [http://scripts.irssi.org/ plugins] that can help you tweak it's look and behavior.

Comment: irssi + revolutionary theme (http://www.irssi.org/themefiles/revolutionary.theme) = :D

Comment: I have tried irssi but it's not clean. Whenever I do "/network remove NETWORK", all of the necessary text in the config that needs to be removed still remains. Messy config = not good

Comment: pic of the `revolutionary.theme` http://irssi.org/themefiles/revolutionary.png

Answer (score 67):

I would prefer [weechat](http://www.weechat.org/). Apart from having colors and looking awesome it is very customizable.

[image: screenshot]

A very small IRC client is [ii](http://tools.suckless.org/ii/), but has no colors out of the box. It is good for using in shell scripts etc.

Comment: A person switching from irssi to weechat will be as happy as one switching from screen to tmux

Comment: also available via ppa https://launchpad.net/~nesthib/+archive/ubuntu/weechat-stable

Comment: Should we merge both top answers? I'm also using weechat recently...

Comment: Very user friendly for former hexchat users.

Answer (score 7):

Always used [Epic](http://www.epicsol.org/) with the SplitFire script myself.

From their site:

> EPIC's development model is to provide
>   tools to scripters rather than
>   features to end users. Out of the box,
>   EPIC behaves much the same way
>   ircII-2.8.2 did in 1994. To truly
>   leverage EPIC, you will need a [script pack.](http://scripts.epicsol.org/)

Answer (score 4):

[Quassel](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quassel) is a really good client in this way. In addition, it can be split in core and client and hence allow multiple computers all connected with the same user name.

Comment: Didn't know Quassel had a terminal client, does it?

Answer (score 3):

I think one of the best IRC clients (ncurses based) is BitchX. It's included by default in the Fedora distros and it might be, in the future, shipped with Ubuntu.

BitchX had several security vulnerabilities, which were fixed lately. You can check BitchX 1.2 (NEW flavor, very nice) on GitHUB: [Bitchx is awesome!](https://github.com/BitchX/BitchX1.2)

I recommend it for all of you who are nostalgic about good old times, also for those eager to experiment.

Another interesting IRC client is IRCII, you can find it here: [ircII is awesome!](http://www.eterna.com.au/ircii/)

Thanks to all for them!