# What IRC client(s) would allow me to filter out log messages?

Tags: software-recommendation, irc

I have been using *Empathy* and more recently *Pidgin* as my IRC client. But there is one feature missing from both of these clients that keeps bothering me. I want to be able to see *only* what people are actually talking about in each channel. I often like to leave IRC channels open and go back to them and read the messages for the last few hours or days. I saw that IRC clients have been discussed in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8015/what-irc-clients-are-available) and a few others, but I have not found what I am looking for yet.

Here is what I want to see in my IRC client:

- what actual people say

Here is what I **do not** want to see

- message about people entering the room
- people leaving room
- people changing their status messages or what they are known as
- people sneezing
- people's cats sneezing

Anyway, you get the picture.

What IRC clients are available for Ubuntu that would allow me to configure what I see so that I can see what people are talking about -- and nothing else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pidgin has a "Join/Part" plugin that allows you to control filtering of these messages.

The types of controls include filtering based on time away and number of people in the room.

Just go to the Buddy List, then Tools->Plugins and tick "Join/Part".  Hit the "Configure Plugin" button for extra control.

Comment: I did not know about this plugin. It is much better now. thank you!