# Wine fatal IO error 11

Tags: wine

I installed wine on ubuntu. When I run any program for windows it ends unexpectedly. Program name: mIRC

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Release: 16.04

Codename: xenial

Installed packages;

```
xrdp
ubuntu-desktop
xfce4
xfce4-goodies
```

Error log;

```
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:time:GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation (0xc5dadc) stub!
fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
fixme:toolhelp:Heap32ListFirst : stub
fixme:shell:ApplicationAssociationRegistration_QueryCurrentDefault (0x148f38)->(L"http", 1, 1, 0xc550e8)
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} could be created for context 0x17
fixme:font:get_font_unicode_ranges encoding 0 not supported
fixme:font:get_font_unicode_ranges encoding 0 not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {ae1e00aa-3fd5-403c-8a27-2bbdc30cd0e1} could be created for context 0x17
fixme:iphlpapi:GetTcp6Table pTcp6Table 0x15e6450, size 0xc4ae10, order 1: stub
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":13.0"
      after 20968 requests (20968 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":13.0"
      after 253 requests (253 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Next experiment;

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":10.0"
      after 257 requests (257 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Comment: What programs are you trying to run exactly? Have you checked the Wine's database yet?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to use mirc.

Comment: Unrelated, but there are a lot of native alternatives to mIRC.

Comment: Indeed, as commented above, use native! Meanwhile you may want to take a look at this (expand the test results): https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20068

Comment: I use mIRC for Twitch.tv Channel Moderator Bot

Comment: And that matters because...? Are you saying you must use the Windows client? If so, why?

Comment: Because I have to enter the script codes. Like Moobot.

Comment: For that you need an IRC client. Why do you think it must be mIRC? https://askubuntu.com/questions/8015/what-irc-clients-are-available   https://www.tecmint.com/best-irc-clients-for-linux/ and the list goes on and on...

Comment: @MichaelBay I have researched. But I did not find a client that could run mIRC script. This required.

Comment: But i found this; https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1101283.html That's what I want and I think I have to use wine.