# How to chat on IRC via Terminal?

Tags: command-line, irc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coolest looking terminal IRC client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743/coolest-looking-terminal-irc-client)

How to chat on IRC via Terminal?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `irssi` to chat via terminal. You can install it via `sudo apt-get install irssi` and find more information about irssi on this website: http://irssi.org/