# Command-line IRC program?

Tags: command-line, gnome, software-recommendation, irc, tui

I currently use `xchat` as my default IRC program, but I don't really like GUIs, I prefer TUIs, is there an IRC program out there which has a TUI rather than a GUI? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: @Seth: Probably, although it is probably asking a different question though they are similar enough for this question to be closed as a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not [Weechat](https://weechat.org/about/) or [Irssi](http://www.irssi.org/about/).

**Install Weechat:**

```
sudo apt-get install weechat
```

[image]

**Install Irssi:**

```
sudo apt-get install irssi
```

[image]

They are especially nice if you use a tiling wm like i3, I have heard.

And you can find more of them here: [Coolest looking terminal IRC client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743/coolest-looking-terminal-irc-client)

Comment: `irssi` in a screen session is my goto communication method. Never miss anything!